# I'm using EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus this plugin to implement google login but im getting error 12501

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, google-signin

I'm using EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus this plugin to implement google login but im getting error 12501. I am using web app client id which i got from google developer console

Answer (score 0):

for google login you need below lib

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    }
```

tutorial [official link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/)

[tutorial link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/google-login-android-tutorial-integrate-gplus-login/)

Comment: i have used the below dependency

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'

Comment: the second link is not opening

Comment: the first link is the native code while im using javascript

Comment: try second link now

Comment: SHA certificate is essential?

Comment: im using web app client id

Comment: but you ask for android app

Comment: its a cordova app and im using cordova plugin for that